# Change plugin CSS depending on category (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, plugins

I'm working with the plugin [Five-Star Ratings & Reviews](https://codecanyon.net/item/fivestar-ratings-reviews-wp-rating-plugin-for-blogs-review-sites-and-ecommerce-shops/16693757) and my client is requesting that the "stars" (here I used circles in the plugin settings) have different colors depending on the post category. It's not possible to do so in the plugin settings. As it's a svg I don't think it's possible - any ideas?

Here's [the link](http://www.chooseyourbottle.com/bieres/) to one of the posts.

Fyi, I already gave a CSS class to each widget (one five-star rating widget per category page).

Thank you

Comment: so you have your answer, use the class to style it, no ?

Comment: That plugin loads the icons it uses pre-colored server-side like this: `<symbol id="..."><path fill="#...">` CSS could only change the color globally in every place an icon is used. This is a closed-source commercial plugin, you'll have to contact their support.

Comment: @TemaniAfif if I style using CSS it changes the circle background, not the circle itself. example: https://ibb.co/huRtdw